# Remote image as notification icon in Chrome Packaged App?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm writing this app and would like to display Chrome notifications with certain remote images as notification icons.

I am aware that you are not allowed to directly assign the URL of a remote image as the notification icon, so I assume I would first have to download the remote image via some sort function and then use the now local image as a notification icon.

How could this be achieved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried a data URL? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to set the icon attribute of my notification object with the remote image URL string, but the JavaScript console shows an error saying this is not allowed. The only solution that comes to my mind is downloading the image first via JavaScript so it's inside the packaged app itself and then I would be able to use treat it as a local file to be used as the notification icon. Edit: I did some research on data URL as mentioned by sowbug (thank you). I will look into that and come back later reporting whether it works in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like sowbug mentioned in his comment, this can be done through Data URL.
Documentation and example can be found in Google's documentation at: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external